# How to create page that reads a div from another page AND IT FOLLOWS the value changes of it

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my code

```
No. of logs: <p id="count">Counter</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x=0;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "refresh4.htm",
    success: function(result) {
        var html = jQuery('<div>').html(result);



        //alert(html.find("div#first").attr("id"));
        //alert(html.find("div#first").html());
        //alert(html.find("div#first"));

        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=html.find("div#auto").html();


       },
});




</script>
```

My problem is that when the value of the div of the other file (refresh4.htm) changes, the displayed value is the same (actually is the first value that this div has predifined).

Where i can find what other options i have exept .html() and attr(). Is there an equivelant as .innerHTML or .value?

Comment: `.html()` is `innerHTML` and `val()` is `value`

Comment: When does your AJAX is fired??

Comment: You will need a method of detecting a change in the other file, and then you'll have to trigger the AJAX load again-with each trigger. I think the file in which the changes occur should initiate the update.

Comment: @Ozzy Either that or he can polled an AJAX request every now and then with `settimeout(AJAX(), time)` but that is not good practice. this all depends if he can edit the code the file in which the file is change.

Comment: @Sebastien actually you are right, the timeout and update every 60 seconds is pretty much the standard way to do it and probably the easiest, I've seen it done on many Sports websites with live commentary.

Comment: @Ozzy is'nt that better if he could use something like COMET to push data to the client, instead of poling repeatedly with AJAX??? (I've heard of COMET but dont know how it work)

Comment: @Sebastien You can say better than I do, I've never heard of COMET.

Comment: @Ozzy I've seen the principle here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) this migth help George make a choice on what he should use.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new ajax request each time each reasonable period of time.

```
var previousResult = null,
    desiredField,
    refreshData = function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "refresh4.htm",
        success: function(result) {
            //Obtain the field of the html
            desiredField = result.find(".desired-field").html();
            if(!previousResult || desiredField !== previousResult) {
                previousResult = desiredField;
                //Done whatever you want with desiredField
            }
        } 
    });


}

setInterval(refreshData, 4000);
```

Comment: The line of code desiredField = result.find(".desired-field").html(); is ok? I ssuppose i have to put ".div#auto"  or  just "div#auto".